# Cannot get the DIV width to dynamically change with respect to browser size and contents in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a `div`, and I want it to have a certain margin from the left.  It is going to contain a number of images that are `210x210 pixels`. I want the div to resize so that its right side extends only a couple of pixels, that I will set as the margin of the `img` tags. For some reason, the `div` I have extends till the end of the page.

The `div` under question is the one with `id="thumbnails`, and it is contained in another `div` with `id="main"`. Please check the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sodiumnitrate/CfFF5/) for the whole code.  But, here's the relevant part of the code:

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
<div id="thumbnails">
    <img class="thumb" id="1" src="images/portfolio/lorem/thumbs/1.jpg">
    <img class="thumb" id="2" src="images/portfolio/lorem/thumbs/2.jpg">
    <img class="thumb" id="3" src="images/portfolio/lorem/thumbs/3.jpg">
    <img class="thumb" id="4" src="images/portfolio/lorem/thumbs/4.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#main {
background-color: rgba(50,50,50,0.6);
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}

#thumbnails {
margin-left: 300px;
margin-top: 50px;
background: rgba(50,50,50,0.6);
}
```

I should also note that when the browser size is small, I prefer the images to continue in the next row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may not be understanding you properly (so my answer may seem a little obvious), but by default `<div>` is a block-level element, which is 100% width.

So, you'll either need to adjust the display property of `#thumbnails` to accommodate dynamic widths (such as `inline-block`), or set it dynamically with a script. Please do the first option.

Answer (score 0):

Give the div `#thumbnails` a style of `float: left;`

This will give the div a place on the page and allow space either side.
Don't forget, you can use `clear` to give it any space that it needs